# Neo4j: How to avoid out of memory in large but simple transaction

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to add to each node in my database a new property that is just the lowercased variant of the original property:

`MATCH (c:CONCEPT) WHERE c.preferredName IS NOT NULL SET c.preferredName_lc = toLower(c.preferredName) RETURN COUNT(c)`

Due to the large size of nodes in the database I run into memory issues:

`Can't allocate 512 bytes due to exceeding memory limit; used=2147483648, max=2147483648`

Can I somehow break this down to multiple transactions while still staying with such a simple query? Or is there another way to achieve the same result in a more memory-efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use apoc periodic functions

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Feel free to make this an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Tomaž's approach personally, but to offer a less complicated solution for those who don't want to wade into APOC yet.  You can also use a LIMIT to do this in batches,

```
MATCH (c:CONCEPT) 
WHERE c.preferredName IS NOT NULL 
with c limit 1000
SET c.preferredName_lc = toLower(c.preferredName) RETURN COUNT(c)
```

NOTE: you have to run each batch manually (or create a loop) until count(c) returns 0, on the second run you could use a SKIP, or in this case I'd just change the where clause to skip over processed nodes

```
WHERE c.preferredName_lc is NULL and c.preferredName IS NOT NULL
```

The need for iterating over batches is one reason I would use apoc iterate, the second reason is that if your cypher operation allows it you can tell apoc to run batches in parallel...

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/periodic-execution/